# How can I sort 2 categories in ggplots bargraph and sort them in decreasing order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a dataframe set up like so:

```
males <-(1,2,3,4)
females <- (2,4,6,8)

df <- cbind(males, females)
rownames(categories) <- c("category1", "category2", "category3", "category4")

ggplot(df, aes(x=categories, y=males)) + geom_col(color="darkblue", fill="lightblue", size=.8) + theme_light()
```

this lists out the categories but by default its in alphabetical order. I need to list both the male and female vectors (ideally as a mirrored histogram), and list them descending order.

Comment: Some things are missing; I cannot reproduce your data. The `males` and `females` assignment are missing the `c()` and `categories` is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

After correcting your data creation code you can get the data in long format and use facets to plot both males and females.

```
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -category) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=reorder(category, -value), y=value) + 
  geom_col(color="darkblue", fill="lightblue", size=.8) + 
  facet_wrap(~name) + xlab('category') + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]
**data**

```
males <-c(1,2,3,4)
females <- c(2,4,6,8)
df <- data.frame(males, females)
df$category <- c("category1", "category2", "category3", "category4")
```